# How can I get the same data from a variable in every part of the method?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I'm having this dilemma: using a similar code from below:

```
//floatArray[totalKeyPoints] declared just outside this loop
for(int d = 0; d < totalGroups; d++)
    {
        std::string STRING = "";
        QString lk = "test" + QString::number(d) + ".txt";
        std::string kl;
        kl = lk.toStdString();
        std::ifstream infile(kl.c_str());
        //std::cout << "FILEPATH: " << kl.c_str() << std::endl;

        int gl = 0;

        while(endFile != true)
        {
            endFile = infile.eof();
            getline(infile,STRING);
            if(STRING.empty() == false && endFile == false && gl < totalKeyPoints)
            {
                QString temp = STRING.c_str();
                QStringList temp1 = temp.split(" ");
                QString tmp = temp1[0];
                floatArray[gl].response = tmp.toFloat();
                tmp = temp1[1];
                floatArray[gl].angle = tmp.toFloat();
                tmp = temp1[2];
                floatArray[gl].size = tmp.toFloat();
                tmp = temp1[3];
                floatArray[gl].class_id = tmp.toInt();
                if(firstRun2 == true)
                    qDebug() << "A:"
                             << floatArray[gl].response 
                             << floatArray[gl].angle 
                             << floatArray[gl].size 
                             << floatArray[gl].class_id; //TAKE NOTE
                int xs = tmp.toInt();
                kpPerGroup[xs]++;
                gl++;
            }
        }

        infile.close();

        if(d < totalGroups)
        {
            endFile = false;
        }
    }

    for (int d = 0; d < totalKeyPoints; d++)
    {
        if(firstRun2 == true)
            qDebug() << "B:" 
                     << floatArray[d].response 
                     << floatArray[d].angle 
                     << floatArray[d].size << floatArray[d].class_id; //TAKE NOTE
    }
```

I have recorded the output of the two `qDebug` commands in this pastebin: [with A and B](http://pastebin.com/2MQWF1gK)

Why am I getting this behavior? Is there a way for me to be able to have only the SET A values in the entire code?

Comment: It is not really clear what you want. Especially since the title of the question seems to have no relation to its contents.

Comment: `temp`, `tmp`, `temp1`, `tmp = temp1[3]`... what a convoluted code. You should try to simplify it first, maybe you will then find out why it doesn't have the expected output.

Comment: Will be editing the title in a while. Hmmm... I'll think about rewriting it again later, we need this code soon :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you want your "A" debug output to actually be:

```
 qDebug() << "A:" << floatArray[gl].response << floatArray[gl].angle << \ 
                     floatArray[gl].size << floatArray[gl].class_id;
```

using `gl` for all indexes instead of `d` for the last three. In the first loop index `d` appears to be unrelated to `floatarray[]`. At best you'll get incorrect output and at worst an array overflow/crash.

Comment: I didn't want to believe it first but this, taking it for a copy-paste mistake but I think this is close to the truth. If you offset the B output by 32 rows the first column aligns. Ill go with comments above also, clean up the code. But upvote for this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice for cleaning up a bit, it now works finer :))